# Selenium: How to click on a disabled button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, button, disabled-control

I check button availability by xpath because button often change css class:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/button')))
```

But programm can`t find and click that button.
Idk, can I use that method to be clickable, so maybe you know method how to find buttun w/o class/id.

It should wait until button will be clickable and click the button.
full function:

```
try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 900)
        ButtBuy = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/button')))
    except:
        time.sleep(30)
        browser.quit()
    else:
        ButtBuy.click()
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
        ButtConfirm = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]')))
        ButtConfirm.click()
```

I think that xpath isn`t correct, but its correct, i paste xpath by xPath finder extension in Firefox browser, Maybe extension not correct generated xpath.

Button in the appointed time becomes available. And when the button becomes available, the program must click the button.

Html of the button:

[image: html code of button]

Comment: Check if this button is in another iframe,if yes you need to switch iframes

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: better show URL for this page. And put it in question, not in comments.

Comment: did you test `xpath` directly with `find_element` ? Disabled button may not be `clickable`.

Comment: if button has always the same text then you can search by text `//button[contains(@text, "Press Me")]`. But first I would check it with `find_element()` instead of `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable()`. You could also first check only `//button` to see if it can find any button - and later you can try to create more complex `xpath` to get only one button - and you could create it step-by-step

Comment: Try using the relative XPath

Answer (score 0):

### HTML `<button>` disabled Attribute

The [disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) attribute when present implies that the button should be disabled and a ***disabled*** button is **unusable** and **un-clickable**.

The disabled attribute is generally set to refrain a user from clicking on the button until some other condition has been met (like selecting a checkbox, etc). Then, a JavaScript could remove the disabled value, and make the button clickable again.

As per the HTML of the element

[image: HTML]

As the element is having the ***disabled*** attribute set you won't be able to click/interact with it.

Comment: The button is disabled until a certain time, and when it becomes available, the program must click it. How can i do this?

Comment: Sounds like a different question all together. Feel free to raise anew question as per your new requirement.